# Work on very old, compiled MacApp® program

Tags: xcode

possibly it's a stupid question, but I would like to know if it is possible to somehow work on an old program which was made with MacApp® 2.0.1.
When I open this file in e.g. XCode, I got much text. Some parts of this text are readable, some parts are just signs like:

[image]

This old program runs on an Mac OS 9 (i think).

Is it perhaps possible to open it with a version of pascal? or is MacApp® still available somewhere?

It would be cool at least to see what's behind the unreadable sign.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt it. The MacApp framework was based on Object Pascal, so without the old compiler, tools, and hardware there probably isn't much you can do with it.

Comment: Free Pascal supports a larger subset of the MW pascal dialect in its mac mode. (which is distinct from Delphi modes). Afaik there was a macapp version for PPC for a while, maybe they killed the biggest amounts assembler with that port.

Answer (score -1):

MacApp still exists and it is still maintained. The latest version includes a native Arm64 build for Apple Silicon Macs.

http://adriaan.biz/macapp/index.html

Comment: That link provides no indication that (1) this ostensible modern version of MacApp is obtainable or (2) it could open and compile this old project.